# Solving Quadratic Formula

Tags: python, math, quadratic, equation-solving

I'm writing a program to solve quadratic equations using the quadratic formula but it only works when a = 1 but i want it to work when a is more than 1

Here is my code:

```
import math

def solve(a, b, c):

    x = ((-1)* b + math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a
    print "x = %s" %x
    print "or"
    y = ((-1)* b - math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a
    print "x = %s" %x




while 1:
    a = int(raw_input("Enter A :"))
    b = int(raw_input("Enter B :"))
    c = int(raw_input("Enter C :")) 
    solve(a, b, c)
```

It works with 1 but when I use a number more than one when i use say 4 i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Factor.py", line 18, in <module>
    solve(a, b, c)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Factor.py", line 5, in solve
    x = ((-1)* b + math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a
ValueError: math domain error
```

is there a way around this if so help!!

Comment: yes you should move the function definition out of that `while` loop

Comment: its the loop i could do while True: but i thought while 1: was faster and i see your right i dont need the function in the loop

Comment: @ChristianCareaga hmmmmm I highly doubt that it's faster, if it is it would be nanoseconds difference...

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114740/negative-pow-in-python

Comment: @jamylak oh OK well then it doesn't matter which one then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problems are here:

1. operator precedence: your `/2*a` should be `/(2*a)` to work correctly.
2. the domain of `sqrt`: `math.sqrt` bails on negative numbers.
3. **Edit 2:** `y = ...` just after `print "or"` should be `x = ...`

To fix the latter, you'll need some sort of conditional:

```
disc = b**2 - 4*a*c
sqrtdisc = math.sqrt(disc) if disc >= 0 else math.sqrt(-disc)*1j
```

**Edit:** You could also use `cmath.sqrt`, which automatically handles negative numbers:

```
disc = b**2 - 4*a*c
sqrtdisc = cmath.sqrt(disc)
```

(Thanks to various other answerers for effectively letting me know that `cmath` exists.)

Comment: +1 -- this seems to be the only answer which points out the `/2*a` problem.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for why you're getting `ValueError` is that your expression `b**2-4*a*c` is returning a negative value, which is not allowed for `math.sqrt`.

```
>>> math.sqrt(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-38-5234f21f3b4d>", line 1, in <module>
    math.sqrt(-1)
ValueError: math domain error
```

use `cmath.sqrt` to handle negative values as well:

```
>>> import cmath
>>> cmath.sqrt(-1)
1j
```

Answer (score 5):

To handle complex numbers use cmath instead.

```
import cmath
cmath.sqrt(negativenumber)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a `math domain error` because you're giving a negative value to `math.sqrt`.  This is likely happening as you increase `a` because you aren't increasing `b` by enough to have `b**2-4*a*c` give a positive value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this to get your roots:

```
def roots(a, b, c):

    def getDiscriminant(a, b, c,Error = "Imaginary Roots"):
        try:
            return (b ** 2 - (4 * a * c)) ** .5
        except:
            return Error

    D = getDiscriminant(a, b, c) 

    if D == False:
        return False

    b = -b
    a = 2 * a

    firstroot = float((b + D) / float(a))
    secondroot = float((b - D) / float(a))

    return (firstroot,secondroot)
```