# ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power

Tags: python

When I tried this in terminal

```
>>> (-3.66/26.32)**0.2
```

I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
```

However, I am able to do this in two steps like,

```
>>> (-3.66/26.32)
-0.13905775075987842
>>> -0.13905775075987842 ** 0.2
-0.6739676327771593
```

Why this behaviour? What is the way to solve this in single line?

Comment: (possibly) related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114740/negative-pow-in-python

Comment: @Haidro, Yes I have seen the question, but my question is          (-1.07) ** 1.3 is throwing error but -1.07 ** 1.3 is not throwing error why ?

Comment: I think this relates to complex numbers.  The square root (fractional power) of negative 1 is i.  It bales when it thinks it's getting into complex number territory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Raising to a power takes precedence over the unary minus sign.

So you have `-(0.13905775075987842 ** 0.2)` and not `(-0.13905775075987842) ** 0.2` as you expect:

```
>>> -0.13905775075987842 ** 0.2
-0.6739676327771593
>>> (-0.13905775075987842) ** 0.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
```

If you want it to work you should write `(-3.66/26.32 + 0j)**0.2`

```
>>> (-3.66/26.32 + 0j)**0.2
(0.5452512685753758+0.39614823506888347j)
```

Or switch Python 3 as noted by @TimPietzcker.

Comment: You can also promote to a complex number using a cast: `x = -1; complex(x)**0.5`

Comment: @Prashant, that's basically the same as `-1 + 0j`

Comment: Yes, it is. Just adding another way it can be done. It's such a small note, it doesn't deserve a separate answer.

Answer (score 8):

Switch to Python 3 which automatically promotes the result to a complex number:

```
>>> (-3.66/26.32)**0.2
(0.5452512685753758+0.39614823506888347j)
```

Comment: My Boss only can take the decision.

Comment: This can't be done in Python 2 because officially complex numbers are an optional feature enabled at compile time. Not that I know of any installation that ever decided to turn off the default-on switch.