# Does this Python error 'ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power' have an error?

Tags: python, runtime-error

I have a problem with the following code :

```
- k_cav*((Tcav*b**3*Pr/((T3+T2)*v**2))**4.42)**0.091/b
```

It throws the error shown in the title, but I have ensured that the base of the fractional power (0.091) is positive for all possible value. `Tcav = abs(T3-T2), b = 0.01, Pr = 0.72, v = 1.34*10**(-5)`, T3 and T2 are temperatures in kelvin around 285.

It should be mentioned that the calculation is a part of a huge calculation, which is repeated several times to determined several temperatures via the Newton–Raphson numerical root finding method, and that **the error only occurs after several iterations.**

Can any body help me with a solution on this problem. I have no clue about what to do about it.

Comment: Have you tried breaking the computation down into steps so that you can see exactly where the failure is?

Comment: Actually this part is a sub part, but I can try to break it further down.

Comment: Ok. If I break the formula into two lines, `-k_cav` and `*((Tcav*b**3*Pr/((T3+T2)*v**2))**4.42)**0.091/b` the error actually appears in the line of `-k_cav`.

Comment: Can you print out the values of the variables when you get the error?

Comment: Is it possible that `k_cav` is a negative value then?

Comment: @NiekdeKlein The values just before the error is:

`k_cav = 2.41,
Tcav = 0.140002665605,
b = 0.01,
Pr = 0.72,
T3 = 292.871800119,
T2 = 292.881839854,
v = 1.34e-05,`

Comment: @JoséM.Benítez The value of k_cav is positive (and becomes negative due to the minus sign), but tis value does not change during the computation.

Comment: Copying those values into an interpreter and running the formula appears to work fine - it gives an answer around -236.9

Comment: What version of Python are you using? For me it also works with those values.

Comment: It's working for me too. Raising to a power takes precedence over the negative sign, so that should be ok.

Comment: That doesn't break it down, that just puts it on multiple lines.

Comment: @Christoffer Is it `Tcav` really calculated through `Tcav = abs(T3 - T2)`? Because the values you just gave don't seem to say it so, do they?

Comment: My way of localizing the error was not the right way, as some of you also have indicated. I found out that the ValueError was located at another line, even though my editor was pointing at the line is have posted here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use `try`/`except` to catch the error and *then* print out the variable's values.  This way you can be sure to see the culprit:

```
try:
    computedValue = - k_cav*((Tcav*b**3*Pr/((T3+T2)*v**2))**4.42)**0.091/b
except ValueError:
    print k_cav, Tcav, b, Pr, T3, T2, v
    raise
doWhateverYouDoWith(computedValue)
```

Comment: I didn't know this 'try and except' thing (I'm am quite new to Python and coding in general) but it help me to find where the error was, and I'm now handling it with something similar to you code piece.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 consider the precedence of the negative (it is resolved in Python 3). 
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747124/valueerror-negative-number-cannot-be-raised-to-a-fractional-power) out, a similar issue.