# Strange behaviour when raising numbers to the power of zero in Python

Tags: python, math

I am using Python 2.7.5. When raising an int to the power of zero you would expect to see either -1 or 1 depending on whether the numerator was positive or negative.

Typing directly into the python interpreter yields the following:

```
>>> -2418**0
-1
```

This is the correct answer. However when I type this into the same interpretter:

```
>>> result = -2481
>>> result**0
1
```

the answer is 1 instead of -1. Using the `complex` builtin [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747124/valueerror-negative-number-cannot-be-raised-to-a-fractional-power) has no effect on the outcome.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why would you expect it to be -1? 1 is (according to the definition I was taught) the correct answer.

The first gives the incorrect answer due to operator precedence.

```
(-1)**0 = 1

-1**0 = -(1**0) = -(1) = -1
```

See Wikipedia for the definition of the 0 exponent: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_exponent

Comment: Ah! As I thought, the answer is that I am a moron. I checked this problem on my calculator and on google but they fell victim to the same precedence problem.

Despite the answer being obvious I think I will leave this post intact so that anyone making the same mistake will see it.

Comment: @jhrf the precedence issue is actually explained in the question you already linked to - the accepted answer opens with *"Raising to a power takes precedence over the unary minus sign."*

Comment: You are correct. I now see that. But when I read that I was still under the impression that I was supposed to see -1 as the result. I thought I was right and python was wrong. If I knew I was wrong in the first place I wouldn't have posted this question.

Answer (score 3):

`-2418**0` is interpreted (mathematically) as `-1 * (2418**0)` so the answer is `-1 * 1 = -1`. Exponentiation happens before multiplication.

In your second example you bind the variable `result` to `-1`. The next line takes the variable `result` and raises it to the power of `0` so you get `1`. In other words you're doing `(-1)**0`.

`n**0` is `1` for any real number `n`... except `0`: technically `0**0` is undefined, although Python will still return `0**0 == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your maths is wrong. `(-2481)**0` should be 1.

According to wikipedia, `Any nonzero number raised by the exponent 0 is 1`.