# Python - TypeError: can't convert complex to float

Tags: python, types, typeerror

I need some help with this code for a school project.

```
import math

v = 9.412
g = 9.81
y = -1.5

def radToDeg(x):
    return((x / math.pi) * 180)

def sqrt(x):
    return(x ** 0.5)

def CalculateAngle(x):
    return(radToDeg(math.atan(((v ** 2) + (sqrt((v ** 4) - (g * ((g * x ** 2) + (2 * y * v ** 2)))))) / (g * x))))

print(CalculateAngle(90.0297))
```

When I run the program, I receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/ballista.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(CalculateAngle(float(90.0297)))
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/ballista.py", line 14, in CalculateAngle
    return float(radToDeg(math.atan(((v ** 2) + (sqrt((v ** 4) - (g * ((g * x ** 2) + (2 * y * v ** 2)))))) / (g * x))))
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

Can someone help me fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It seems like your function is set up to accept radians as an input, but you're passing degrees ...

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747124/valueerror-negative-number-cannot-be-raised-to-a-fractional-power)

This may cause due to Raising to a power takes precedence over the unary minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

1) You're calling a function called `radToDeg` with an input angle in degrees. Make sure that you're passing in the right arguments to your functions.

2) Why are you defining your own `sqrt` instead of using `math.sqrt`?

3) When I run this code I get a completely different error: `ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power`. Is this exactly what you're trying to run?