# numpy x**L operator gives NaN if x is a vector of negative floats

Tags: python, numpy

I have encountered a strange behavior of python numpy; if I consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=np.linspace(-1.0, 0.0, 5)
    L=1.65
    y=x**L
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

The vector `y=[nan,nan,nan,nan,0.]`, instead if the code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 5)
    L=1.65
    y=x**L
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

results in `y=[0.,0.10153155,0.31864016,0.62208694,1.]` which is correct.

So the question is what is the problem? Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong? I'm using Python 2.7.11 | Anaconda 4.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot raise negative real numbers to fractional powers

In `python 2.7` try doing `(-1)**1.65` and see the python error

As @Blckknght mention in the comments, given `(-1)**1.65`, `python 3` will automatically return a complex number, instead of raising an exception

To achieve what you want you need to cast the array `x` to complex numbers

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=np.linspace(-1.0, 0.0, 5).astype(np.complex64)
    L=1.65
    y=x**L
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

Check [ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747124/valueerror-negative-number-cannot-be-raised-to-a-fractional-power)
and [How to raise arrays with negative values to fractional power in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898917/how-to-raise-arrays-with-negative-values-to-fractional-power-in-python)

Comment: It's worth noting that Python 3 will automatically return a `complex` value when you do `(-1)**1.65`, rather than raising an exception. That's new behavior though, and `numpy` still behaves the same way.

Comment: Thanks, i was quite sure I was doing something wrong indeed!!! Of course I have to use complex number, thanks again...