# Matplotlib not plotting the imaginary side of the axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to plot this power law equation:
[image: Power law equation]

This is my code. However, when `n < 1`, the plot only plots one side of the equation (the real side not the imaginary side). How do I plot the imaginary side (when `n < 1`)?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 0.4
k = 0.479862
p = 9470
r = np.linspace(-0.0127, 0.0127, 500)
d = 0.0254
u = (n/n+1)*(p/(2*k))** (1/n)*(d**((n+1)/n) - r**((n+1)/n))
plt.xlabel('Radius m')
plt.ylabel('Velocity l/min')
plt.plot(r, u)
```

`n = 0.4` plot

[image: n = 0.4 plot]

It should look similar to this `n=1` or newtonian plot

[image: n=1 or newtonian plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `n` being smaller than 1 or not. The problem arises whenever `(n+1)/n` isn't a perfect integer.  Then, `r**((n+1)/n)` isn't well-defined for floating point numbers, for negative `r`, as explained e.g. in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4353964/12046409). Just try `n = 2`, and you'll notice it also doesn't have a value for any negative `r`.

Please also note that your python formula starts with `(n/n+1)` while your maths formula starts with `(n/(n+1))`.

To draw a symmetric curve, you might just copy and mirror the positive part.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 0.4
k = 0.479862
p = 9470
r = np.linspace(0, 0.0127, 100)
d = 0.0254
u = (n/(n+1))*(p/(2*k))** (1/n)*(d**((n+1)/n) - r**((n+1)/n))

plt.xlabel('Radius m')
plt.ylabel('Velocity l/min')
plt.plot(np.concatenate([-r[::-1], r]), np.concatenate ([u[::-1], u]))
plt.show()
```

Here is the resulting curve with the first factor of the formula adapted (`n/(n+1)`), for `n=0.4`.
[image: resulting plot]

Alternatively, you can convert everything to complex numbers, and plot their real and the imaginary part separately.  Therefore, you convert `r` using `r.astype(np.complex)`. And `np.imag(u)` to get the imaginary part of `u`.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 0.4
k = 0.479862
p = 9470
r = np.linspace(-0.02, 0.02, 500)
r = r.astype(np.complex)
d = 0.0254
u = n / (n + 1) * (p / (2 * k)) ** (1 / n) * (d ** ((n + 1) / n) - r ** ((n + 1) / n))

plt.xlabel('Radius m')
plt.ylabel('Velocity l/min')
plt.plot(r, u, color='dodgerblue', label='real part')
plt.plot(r, np.imag(u), color='crimson', label='imaginary part')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot with real and imaginary part]